# Error when fetching data from database to autocomplete textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form where i am using one autocomplete text box (using ajax autocomplete extender).
Autocomplete functionality is working properly. But When I try to fetch data from database and try to display it in my form values doesn't display on form.

As soon as I comment ajax autocomplete extender from page,all values gets displayed.Why is this happening?

I need that autocomplete functionality in my form.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtContactsSearch" runat="server" autopostback="True"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers"
MinimumPrefixLength="2"
CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10"
TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch"
ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>

public void getdata()
{
 Datatable dt=objdal.getdata();
 Datarow dr=dt=.Rows[0];
 txtContactsSearch.Text=dr["contact"].Tostring();
  //sililar code for remaining textboxes on form  
}
```

Comment: Any code? I cannot guess how you have implemented it.

Comment: When do you invoke `getdata()`? I mean on which which event

Comment: on textchanged event of another textbox in my form

Comment: Does it allow `autopostback`? Isn't that one in any `update panel`?

Comment: yes it allows postback.the whole form is inside update panel.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax AutoComplete  add

OnClientItemSelected="mycustomers" OnClientShowing="clientShowing

```
     Call mycustomers() and clientShowing() in Javascript 

      Function mycustomers(){
      var str = $('#<%=txtname.ClientID %>').val();
       var partsOfStr = str.split(",");
        $.trim("partsOfStr");

      //spilt your string like this 
        $('#<%=txtname.ClientID %>').val(partsOfStr[0]);
        $('#<%=txtcontact.ClientID %>').val(partsOfStr[1]);


       }

       function clientShowing(source, args) {
        var popup = source._completionListElement;
        var height = popup.scrollHeight;
        var width = popup.scrollWidth;
        source._popupBehavior._element.style.height = "130px";
        source._popupBehavior._element.style.zIndex = 100000;
        //This iframe's height and width should be smaller than the CompletionList but bigger     than the DropDownList
        var iframe1 = "<IFRAME id='iframe1' style=' height:200px; width:10px; position:absolute; z-index:99999;border:0px; border-style:none; border-width:0px; ' ></IFRAME>";
        popup.innerHTML = iframe1 + popup.innerHTML;
    }
```

Call a webservice method in your .cs page

```
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod (EnableSession=true)]


     public static List<string> SearchCustomers(string prefixText, int count)
     {
       sql = Select Name+ ',' + Contact+ ',' as Name From Table  where Name Like '%'+@Name+'%' 

       // Find the datatable or Dataset 

         // THEN add
        List<string> Contact= new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            Company.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());

        }
        return Contact;
    }
      }
```